Will multicast(_:) create a new subject for each subscriber
In this code, why debug: multicast triggered.. is printed only once while there are 2 subscribers. Since Apple says multicast(_:) creates a new publisher for each subscriber, shouldn't the print statement being triggered twice?
import Foundation
import Combine

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let upstreamPublisher = Range(1...3).publisher.delay(for: 1, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)

let sharedSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(-1)

// Create a multicast publisher and apply autoconnect
let multicastPublisher = upstreamPublisher
    .multicast({
        print("debug: multicast triggered..")
        return sharedSubject
    })
    .autoconnect()

// Subscriber 1
multicastPublisher
    .sink { value in
        print("Subscriber 1 received value: \(value)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

// Subscriber 2
multicastPublisher
    .sink { value in
        print("Subscriber 2 received value: \(value)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

// Output
//debug: multicast triggered..
//Subscriber 1 received value: -1
//Subscriber 2 received value: -1
//Subscriber 1 received value: 1
//Subscriber 2 received value: 1
//Subscriber 1 received value: 2
//Subscriber 2 received value: 2
//Subscriber 1 received value: 3
//Subscriber 2 received value: 3


Thanks Rob, I think passing "CurrentValueSubject" will be helpful if you want each subscriber to receive an initial value, otherwise we could just use shared(), which is the same as multicast + pass through subject + implicit autoconnect()

And I submitted a feedback on the Documentation to Apple, in case their documentation is incorrect

Agreed! That's why I said "implicit" autoconnect. Apple is using this phrase in share() opeartor: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/share() in the "Tip" notes: Publishers.Share is effectively a combination of the Publishers.Multicast and PassthroughSubject publishers, with an implicit autoconnect().

And yes agreed, we usually don't want to use autoconnect for multicast, because the purpose of using multicast is often because we want to delay the connection until all subscribers have subscribed to the publisher

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The multicast(_:) appears to call its closure just once, not repeatedly as each subscriber attaches to it. (The ostensible notion of “create a new Subject each time a subscriber attaches to the multicast publisher” seems to entirely defeat the purpose of multicast, namely you only want a single call to your publisher’s receive<S>(subscriber:) method.)
To my eye, this looks like a mistake in the documentation: The difference between multicast(subject:) and multicast(_:) appears to be simply that the former takes a Subject, and the latter takes a closure that returns a Subject.

A few observations. Consider this rendition of your code snippet:
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let upstreamPublisher = (1...3).publisher
    .map { _ in Int.random(in: 0...100) }

// Create a multicast publisher
let multicastPublisher = upstreamPublisher
    .multicast {
        print("debug: multicast triggered…")
        return PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    }

// Subscriber 1
multicastPublisher
    .sink { value in
        print("Subscriber 1 received value: \(value)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

// Subscriber 2
multicastPublisher
    .sink { value in
        print("Subscriber 2 received value: \(value)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

// Connect
multicastPublisher.connect()
    .store(in: &cancellables)

This entails a few modifications from the original code snippet:

I personally would avoid using autoconnect() in this scenario, but would instead defer the connect() until all the subscribers had been added.
The point in multicast functions returning a “connectable” publisher is so that you can defer the connecting until some future point in the code. Because I now defer connect(), I can remove the delay which was only necessary to prevent the first subscriber from exhausting the sequence before the second subscriber got to it. (Obviously, you can add the delay back, if you want: My point is merely that if you defer the connect(), no delay is necessary.)

I have added a map to a random integer, as that might better illustrate the utility of multicasting (where each subscriber receives the same values; if you remove the multicast in this rendition with map, each subscriber will get different series of random values).

I also prefer PassThroughSubject for this use-case, to avoid arbitrary sentinel values, but obviously use CurrentValueSubject if that is what your scenario calls for.


Anyway, that results in:
debug: multicast triggered…
Subscriber 2 received value: 96
Subscriber 1 received value: 96
Subscriber 2 received value: 32
Subscriber 1 received value: 32
Subscriber 2 received value: 57
Subscriber 1 received value: 57

